# How to revoke a command of git "git checkout -m filename"

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I want to push a local file to a GitHub repository, but I used:

```
git checkout -m filename
```

so, my local file was overwritten. I would like to know how to recover from this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the commit you were on before you made the changes to the file and then commit again. Assuming the file is called filename and you were on commit 1 then:

```
git checkout HEAD^
git commit -a
git push -f
```

To summarise, when you checkout an older commit, you're committing all the changes you made since that commit. If you don't want those changes, you have to use the -f option to force the commit.

Answer (score 0):

> ... my [working tree] file was overwritten. I would like to know how to recover from this.

*Git* is of little or no help here (though see footnote 2).  Files in your working tree—the files you can see, read, and write—are not actually *in* Git.  At best, they were, at some earlier point, copied *out of* Git.  If what you want is to copy the file *out* of Git again, `git checkout`—or, in Git 2.23 or later, `git restore`<sup>1</sup>—lets you do that.  But if you had unsaved work in your working tree, and told Git to destroy it, and Git did ... well, in this case, *Git* did not first save that unsaved work anywhere.  So you can't get it back *from Git*.

If you are on macOS and have Time Machine backups going, see if you can get the old version of the file from there.  If you're on some other OS, check into that OS's backup facilities.  The *OS* may give you a way to restore the old version of the file.

> I want to push a local file to a GitHub repository ...

Note that Git does not push *files*.  Git pushes *commits*.  Each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file.  To update some file, you check out the entire commit—*all* the files—so that Git copies them out of some commit into your *working tree*.  These files *aren't* in Git: they're actually useful for doing work.

The files inside a Git commit are in a read-only, frozen-for-all-time format that only Git can read and literally *nothing*, not even Git itself, can overwrite, so they're quite useless for doing any actual work.  That's why Git has to copy them out somewhere.

Anyway, now that the files are in *your* area—your working tree—you can work on them.  When you've updated some set of files, you must run `git add` to get Git to prepare them for being committed.  This compresses (or "freeze-dries" as I sometimes like to say) the working tree file to get it ready to go into your *next* commit.  Until this point, the freeze-dried—or compressed and de-duplicated—copy of the file that's ready to go into the *next* commit is still the same as the copy that came out of *this* commit.

Now that you've updated your *proposed next commit*, and `git status` shows that these files are "staged for commit"—which just means that the freeze-dried file in Git's index aka staging-area no longer matches the freeze-dried file in the *current* commit—running `git commit` will gather the rest of what Git needs to make the new commit (the "metadata").  It will then write out that new commit, which will hold a snapshot of *every* file—de-duplicated, so that where your new commit matches the current one, there's almost no disk space needed—and your new commit will *become* your current commit.  *Now* you have something you can `git push`: a commit.

Until you commit, though, files in your working tree are just in your working tree.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git checkout` still exists in Git 2.23 and later versions.  It has just *also* been split into the "safe" command, `git switch`, and the "unsafe" one, `git restore`, so that you won't accidentally run an unsafe `git checkout` while thinking you're running a safe command.

The safe and unsafe modifiers in quotes here refer to the way that `git switch` tries to make sure Git *won't* destroy any in-progress but un-committed work in your working tree, while `git restore` assumes that you understand that you just asked to destroy in-progress work, and will happily do so.  The `git checkout` command combines both actions: there's a "safe" form of checkout that first checks whether it's going to destroy unsaved work, and an "unsafe" form that assumes that you really *meant* to destroy unsaved work.

<sup>2</sup>If you *have* run `git add`, before this `git checkout` that overwrite the working tree copy, there *is* some hope.  This is a bit complicated, but when `git add` took your work-tree file and freeze-dried it, it had to *save* the freeze-dried copy somewhere.  The place Git saves this is in the repository.  So the `git add` actually puts a copy of the file in the repository.

There are some stumbling blocks with *recovering* such a file:

- The file's *name* is *not* in the repository: the `git add` step saves the file's name in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, creating or updating a mode-name-hash tuple.  The `git checkout` will have replaced that index entry, so that there's no mode-name-hash tuple to find any more.
- The contents will have been automatically de-duplicated.  If they matched any *earlier* commit, that means the hash will be that from some earlier commit, and the rest of this won't do any good: the contents *are* in the Git repository but this little trick here won't help.

If these stumbling blocks aren't too much of a problem, though, running `git fsck --lost-found` will make Git scour through the entire Git object database and find any so-called *dangling blobs*.  One of these will be your file contents.  None of them have useful *names*, but all of them will be copied—after expanding out of freeze-dried format—into `.git/lost-found/other`.  So you can now peruse all the files inside `.git/lost-found/other` and see if any of them hold the content you want back.  If so, copy that file somewhere.  Then just remove the entire `other` and `commit` directories in the `.git/lost-found` directory, to undo the effects of `git fsck` here.  (Or just leave them, if you don't mind the extra disk space they take.)